# What is James's middle name?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge, limerick

*There once was a man called James*
*who liked to use different names*
*If you're slick and astute*
*by removing the fruit*
*your favorite flava remains*

What was his middle name?

Comment: I feel like this may be something to do with the various Jamess that have ruled England and Scotland with different numbers (1st one being King James VI and I) because they liked to use different names (James VI in Scotland, James I in England).

But I still don't know what flava means (Apparantly it's Latin for Yellow (plural))

Comment: @Artyer [I found this.](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=flava)

Comment: Ah, James "Wholikedtousedifferentnamesifyoureslickandastutebyremovingthefruityourfavoriteflava" Remains... good friend of mine.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> His middle name is Ambrose.
> The riddle is a limerick. Removing the fruit, "Lime", leaves "Rick". This points towards the musician Rick James, who used quite a few different names, one of them "Slick Rick". His real name was James Ambrose Johnson.
> Also, "Favorite Flava" is a song from his album "Urban Rhapsody".

Comment: what a great riddle.